# removing duplicates - ** only when the duplicates occur in sequence

Tags: matlab, vector, duplicates, sequence

I would like to do something similar to the following, except I would only like to remove 'g' and'g' because they are the duplicates that occur one after each other. I would also like to keep the sequence the same.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

I have this cell array in MATLAB:

```
y = { 'd' 'f' 'a' 'g' 'g' 'w' 'a' 'h'}


ans =

'd'    'f'    'a'    'w'    'a'    'h'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Tags "vector", "duplicates" and "sequence" are worthless without the "matlab" tags. You are not looking for a vector specialist. You are looking for a matlab specialist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an error in my first answer (below) when used on multiple duplicates (thanks grantnz). Here's an updated version:

```
>> y = { 'd' 'f' 'a' 'g' 'g' 'w' 'a' 'h' 'h' 'i' 'i' 'j'};
>> i = find(diff(char(y)) == 0);
>> y([i; i+1]) = []

y = 

    'd'    'f'    'a'    'w'    'a'    'j'
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

If your "cell vector" always contains only single character elements you can do the following:

```
>> y = { 'd' 'f' 'a' 'g' 'g' 'w' 'a' 'h'}

y = 

    'd'    'f'    'a'    'g'    'g'    'w'    'a'    'h'

>> y(find(diff(char(y)) == 0) + [0 1]) = []

y = 

    'd'    'f'    'a'    'w'    'a'    'h'
```

Comment: Have you tried your solution with more than one duplicate?  I think you will get a 'Matrix dimensions must agree' error.

Comment: thanks!  they all seem to work well.          Would it be easy to modify this code to excise triplicates instead? Is it possible to use the diff between i, i+1 and i+2 or something like that?                       >> y = { 'd' 'f' 'a' 'g' 'g' 'g' 'w' 'a' 'h' 'h' 'i' 'i' 'j'};
>> i = find(diff(char(y)) == 0);
>> y([i; i+1]) = []

Comment: @jess: Yes, this approach will work as it is for any number of consecutive duplicates.

Comment: great.  thanks very much! I think I am starting to see the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it like this: you want to keep an element if and only if either (1) it's the first element or (2) its predecessor is different from it *and* either (3) it's the last element or (4) its successor is different from it. So:

```
y([true ~strcmp(y(1:(end-1)),y(2:end))] & [~strcmp(y(1:(end-1)),y(2:end)) true])
```

or, perhaps better,

```
different = ~strcmp(y(1:(end-1)),y(2:end));
result = y([true different] & [different true]);
```

Comment: This solution does not quite fit the question's requirements. _Both_ elements should be removed in the case of consecutive duplicates.

Comment: Whoops, you're right: I misread the question. Now fixed (so I'm afraid your comment will not make sense to anyone who doesn't read this one and realise I've edited my answer; sorry).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 y([ diff([y{:}]) ~= 0 true])
```

or slightly more compactly

```
 y(diff([y{:}]) == 0) = []
```

Correction : The above wont remove both the duplicates

```
ind = diff([y{:}]) == 0;
y([ind 0] | [0 ind]) = []
```

BTW, this works even if there are multiple duplicate sequences

eg,

```
y = { 'd' 'f' 'a' 'g' 'g' 'w' 'a' 'h' 'h'};
ind = diff([y{:}]) == 0;

y([ind 0] | [0 ind]) = []

y = 

     'd'    'f'    'a'    'w'    'a'
```

Comment: This solution does not remove both duplicates as required.