# create matlab column based function

Tags: arrays, matlab, duplicates, octave

Does anybody know how to solve

[removing duplicates - ** only when the duplicates occur in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333092/removing-duplicates-only-when-the-duplicates-occur-in-sequence)

in Octave? The accepted solution is using `diff`.

Matlab's `diff` seems to behave differently than the Octave's one and doesn't accept characters.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: A character can be represented as an int, have you tried typecasting?

Comment: thanks for the idea... the diff(), it doesn't make any difference whether it's a char or an int... might be an idea. trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the characters to their ASCII codes, then run the solution as given:

```
a = {'d' 'f' 'a' 'g' 'g' 'w' 'a' 'h'};
aa = cellfun(@(c) c-0, a);             %# convert to ASCII

idx = find(diff(aa) == 0);
a([idx idx+1]) = [];
```

Comment: that's exactly what I did the day - is somewhat ago now. thanks! =)

Comment: @Atmocreations: you're welcome. In the future, you could post a solution to your own problem if you found it.

Comment: Thanks, I know about that. But "AlwaysWrong" already gave the answer indirectly...